# How to place a widget beside a div/text so that they display as a continuous line

Tags: widgets

An example will probably provide the best base context. I want to achieve:

Headline
widget (linked text/image)... linked text

Point of difficulty: displaying these so that they read as one line, running on from the Widget directly to the text, and then wrapping the line without reformatting the space between the two elements, ideally:

Headline

widget widget widget linked text linked text linked text linked

text linked text

My current php is:

```
<?php dynamic_sidebar('under-headline-widget'); ?>
<p class="post-info"> Written by <a href... </a> ... ?>
```

and my HTML is:

```
    <div class="center-column">
    <h2>Headline</h2>
    <div class="widget-item" id="text-4">           
    <div class="textwidget">some text here
    </div>
    </div>        <p class="post-info">
    Written by ...

    ... next div
```

Thanks, Community

Comment: Sounds like a purely CSS challenge.  Is your "linked text" widget content or separate from the widget entirely? Getting your widgets to line up horizontally is a matter of float or inline display properties.

Comment: Hi, they are separate, and I have tried including them in floated divs of several arrangements. This doesn't allow me to run them as a continuous stream that wraps elegantly though. it creates two boxes that are always beside eachother, so when the right div text wraps, it wraps within that box (not back to the far-left margin). Also, I have not been able to code the text to begin at any point where the widget ends, but rather have only been able to adjust percentages and pixels of the size I allow it.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving this (in a limited fashion) by just using text, which I linked to the function I wanted using javascript on click. This may not work for others still trying to do what my original intention had been, but maybe this will solve your problem too